# symfony2 multiple choice form to comma separated string

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a `color` database column (varchar)

I am using symfony2 form and selectize (UI looks like Max Item sections from http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

It submits as a array and I have no idea how to change it to comma separated string and save it to database. I keep getting "This value is not valid." when i submit.

Form Type

```
$builder
            ->add('ram', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => [],
            ))
            ->add('color', 'choice', array(
                "label" => "Warna",
                'choices' => $colorOptions,
                'multiple' => true
            ));
```

[image: UI layout]

In the database column, i would like to save as `black,white`

[image: yml]

[image: entity]

Comment: Form is mapped to entity? If yes, show us mapping of your entity.

Comment: Please don't post code as image, it's hard to use if we want to answer or try your code

Comment: maybe this will help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html